# Prove that $1+2^1+2^2+\ldots +2^n=2^{n+1}-1$ using induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

> For all integers $n\ge 1$ prove the following statement using mathematical induction.

$$1+2^1+2^2+\ldots +2^n=2^{n+1}-1$$

The first part of the question ask me to prove the base step:

So I set $n=1$ and plugged it in but the answer is not correct (unless I made a silly arithmetic error somewhere).

$2^1=2^{1+1}-1$

$2=2^{2}-1$

$2=4-1$

$2=3$

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: When $n=1$ the left-hand side is $1+2^1$. This is $3$. You already verified that the right-hand side is $3$.

Comment: Suggestion for proving this (without induction): Think about the base-2 representation of that sum.

Comment: Another suggestion without induction:$$\eqalign{1+LHS&=1+1+2+4+8+\cdots+2^n\cr &=2+2+4+8+\cdots+2^n\cr &=4+4+8+\cdots+2^n\cr &=\cdots\cr&=2^n+2^n\cr &=2^{n+1}\ .\cr}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is quite simple: You omitted the initial "$1+\cdots$".

When $n=0$ the identity says $1 = 2 - 1$, i.e. $2^0=2^{0+1}-1$.  You can take that to be the base step.

Comment: Typically that part is left out of the base step, is it included here because it is not raised to an $n$ power?

Comment: @inquisitor : The number $1$ is $2^0$.  You could have given as the base step just $1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: OK, I think I must have been confused by the $n \ge 1$.

Comment: You can start with $n=1$, in which case the base step says $1+2 = 2^0+2^1 = 2^2-1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

Your LHS should be $1 + \ldots + 2^n = 1 + \ldots + 2^1 = 1 + 2^1 = 3$

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer for this question but from **proof without words**.
[image]